# C# MODI ERROR: OCR text in image

Tags: c#, image, sharepoint, ocr, modi

My app use OCR (modi SharePoint 2017) on a list images for return all images that contains this text.
It's work, but the app bug and stop at a time. Ex: I selected 32.000 images and I call the method, for some hours it's working and at a time it's stop and I don't know why.
The app raise 8 errors before stop and when I restart on a image where error is appeared, it's work.

```
try
{
    modiDocument = new Document();
    modiDocument.Create(filePath);
    modiDocument.OCR(MiLANGUAGES.miLANG_FRENCH, false, false);

    MODI.Image modiImage = (modiDocument.Images[0] as MODI.Image);
    string extractedText = modiImage.Layout.Text;

    return extractedText;               
}
catch (Exception ex)
{                
   Console.WriteLine(
        "Une exception a eu lieu : {0}.",
        ex.Message);
    writeFileBug(filePath);
    return null;

}
finally
{
    modiDocument.Close();
}
```

The errors:

```
Exception levée : 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' dans teste ocr.exe
Une exception a eu lieu : OCR running error.
Exception levée : 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' dans teste ocr.exe
Une exception a eu lieu : OCR running error.
Exception levée : 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' dans teste ocr.exe
Une exception a eu lieu : OCR running error.
Exception levée : 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' dans teste ocr.exe
Une exception a eu lieu : OCR running error.
Exception levée : 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' dans teste ocr.exe
Une exception a eu lieu : OCR running error.
Exception levée : 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' dans teste ocr.exe
Une exception a eu lieu : OCR running error.
Exception levée : 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' dans teste ocr.exe
Une exception a eu lieu : OCR running error.
Exception levée : 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' dans teste ocr.exe
Une exception a eu lieu : OCR running error.
Le programme '[15152] teste ocr.vshost.exe' s'est arrêté avec le code -1073740791 (0xc0000409).
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting `-1073740791 (0xc0000409)` indicates a buffer overflow.([source](http://www.febooti.com/products/automation-workshop/online-help/events/run-dos-cmd-command/exit-codes/))

Check if any other of the objects being created in your code need to be disposed in your `finally` block.

Comment: the code that extract the text with OCR is completely in the first post (public string ExtractTextFromImage(string filePath)). Nothing else to dispose because it's the only code that uses OCR